# Img not displaying when route is changed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have an image tag

```
<img src="uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%; height: 100%;" alt="asdasd asd">
```

It is displayed when the url in web.php is

```
Route::get('/product', 'FlashCartController@find_product');
```

But when I change it to

```
Route::get('/product/search', 'FlashCartController@find_product');
```

Image doesn't display. What is the error or issue behind it?

Comment: src will be as `src="/uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png" `

Comment: You're getting an issue because of the URI. You can use `asset()` I think it is or just put a `/` in front of your `uploads`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive you should not be using static paths, "uploads/store/.."
If it is a static image ( used to design or something front end) it should be under the public folder, for example

1. Save image in "/public/uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png"
2. (Use this to retrieve image) src="{{URL::asset('uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png')}}"

If it is an image to be changed in some sort of backoffice, then you should probably look at the storage docs ( https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem )

Answer (score 2):

Change your image src to this `src="/uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png"`

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
{!! HTML::image("public/uploads/store/products/1-1486038295-1-1-qYv3f.png", "png", array()) !!}
```